# Install RDS with Powershell on local server

Tags: powershell, rds

I'm pretty new to Powershell and wanted to create a script that install the Remote Desktop Service which is a prerequisite of my application. (I'm on R2012 btw)

I already found that it's possible to do so with a domain account on a remote server (due to the restart needed during installation). I used:

```
New-RDSessionDeployment [-ConnectionBroker] <String> [-SessionHost] <String[]> [[-WebAccessServer] <String> ]
```

Now, I want to install RDS on my local server when I launch my Powershell script (as I can do with the Server Manager GUI). The goal is to install RDS and my application in the same Powershell script without the need to do it using a remote server.

Is it possible to do so ? Should I use the role-based RDS installation or is there any tricks I can use to bypass the local server restart (like maybe a workflow) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add the RDS Feature

```
Add-WindowsFeature –Name RDS-RD-Server –IncludeAllSubFeature -Restart
```

If you don't include `-Restart` the restart is not performed - but will be needed before the feature can be used.

Answer (score 2):

Yes ,  on the context that you need to use **New-SessionDeployment** but having being said you still need the **remotedesktop** module to be imported first using

> Import-Module RemoteDesktop

Now you need have RD Connection Broker, RD Web Access, and RD Session Host by using:

> New-SessionDeployment –ConnectionBroker server.domain.com
>   –WebAccessServer server.domain.com –SessionHost server.domain.com

Now you need a Licensing Role, use:

> Add-RDServer -Server server2.domain.com -Role RDS-LICENSING
>   -ConnectionBroker server1.domain.com

NOw we have use the deployment for the licensing , use :

> Set-RDLicenseConfiguration -LicenseServer server2.domain.com -Mode PerUser
>   -ConnectionBroker server1.domain.com

Now you can use ,

**New-RDSessionCollection**  and can publish **New-RDRemoteapp**

This should help you in proceeding further.

Comment: Without restart it is not possible to install RDS. Since its a server role, you cannot bypass it. 

This should suffice your need. If it helps you in the installation like the answer. Goodluck